# Soft 404 occurs in empty internal search results, What to do?

Tags: indexing, seo, http-status-code-404, google-search-console, google-crawlers

According to the article:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/181708?hl=en
Soft 404 appears because some of search criteria in my Website are empty of items, but I need those pages to be indexed anyway by Google, to prevent those errors from appearing in Webmaster crawl errors, and to ensure that they won't affect the site indexing speed, what should we do?! should we return 404 error code? should we work more on filling all the search combinations or just ignore them?!

Answer (score 6):

you shouldn't index those pages - it's a very bad practice and you should read this post to get a few ideas regarding this case http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/02/faceted-navigation-best-and-5-of-worst.html

Google will remove those pages form index anyway and could give you a penalty due to submitting low value pages to index (panda update).

Common practice is to "noindex, follow" these pages.

If you don't want to have soft 404 messages, you should add more content to the pages - i.e. some recommendations with similar content etc.

Comment: what if i did noindex that pages months ago, and google is telling me soft 404 now?!? What is going wrong?

Comment: What about using 204 instead of 404? I've seen that on some websites. Is it a better choice for SEO?

Comment: The 204 code allows servers to send a successful response _without a body_. I.e. not simply a page empty of items but _no page at all_!